# Julia: What is the perfect way to convert a categorical array to a numeric array?

Tags: arrays, julia, categorical-data

What is the perfect way to convert a categorical array to a simple numeric array?
For example:

```
using CategoricalArrays
a = CategoricalArray(["X", "X", "Y", "Z", "Y", "Y", "Z"])
b = recode(a, "X"=>1, "Y"=>2, "Z"=>3)
```

As a result of the conversion, we still get a categorical array, even if we explicitly specify the type of assigned values:

```
b = recode(a, "X"=>1::Int64, "Y"=>2::Int64, "Z"=>3::Int64)
```

It looks like some other approach is needed here, but I can't think of a direction to look in

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have two natural options:

```
julia> recode(unwrap.(a), "X"=>1, "Y"=>2, "Z"=>3)
7-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 1
 2
 3
 2
 2
 3
```

or

```
julia> mapping = Dict("X"=>1, "Y"=>2, "Z"=>3)
Dict{String, Int64} with 3 entries:
  "Y" => 2
  "Z" => 3
  "X" => 1

julia> [mapping[v] for v in a]
7-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 1
 2
 3
 2
 2
 3
```

the `Dict` approach is slower, but it is more flexible in case you would have many levels to map.

The key function here is `unwrap` that drops the "categorical" notion of `CategoricalValue` (in the `Dict` style `unwrap` gets called automatically)

Also note that if you just want to get the `levelcode`s of the values stored in a `CategoricalArray` (something that R does by default) then you can just do:

```
julia> levelcode.(a)
7-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 1
 2
 3
 2
 2
 3
```

Also note that with `levelcode` `missing` is mapped to `missing`:

```
julia> x = CategoricalArray(["Y", "X", missing, "Z"])
4-element CategoricalArray{Union{Missing, String},1,UInt32}:
 "Y"
 "X"
 missing
 "Z"

julia> levelcode.(x)
4-element Vector{Union{Missing, Int64}}:
 2
 1
  missing
 3
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Bogumił's answers, a possible approach that should be quite fast is:

```
julia> b = recode!(similar(a, Int), a, "X"=>1, "Y"=>2, "Z"=>3)
7-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 1
 2
 3
 2
 2
 3
```

Answer (score 3):

[Bogumił's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67470218/15281224) covers most of the question but I think it could be useful to add one more solution:

```
unwrap.(recode(a, "X"=>1, "Y"=>2, "Z"=>3))
```

As the length of the CategoricalArray grows relative to the number of categories, this solution becomes more performant than any of the other solutions (as of this moment) and seems like a very natural solution to me (it almost identical to OP's attempt). More importantly, the fact that it is more performant for these cases illustrates things about `CategoricalArray`s and what is actually happening when these functions are called.

By calling [`dump`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/io-network/#Base.dump) on `a` you can see the structure of this categorical array. Here is a simplified version:

```
CategoricalVector{String, UInt32, String, CategoricalValue{String, UInt32}, Union{}}
  refs: UInt32[0x00000001, 0x00000001, 0x00000002, 0x00000003, 0x00000002, 0x00000002, 0x00000003]
  pool: CategoricalPool{String, UInt32, CategoricalValue{String, UInt32}}
    levels: String["X","Y","Z"]
    invindex: Dict{String, UInt32}("Y" => 0x00000002, "Z" => 0x00000003, "X" => 0x00000001)
```

Each category is encoded as an `UInt32`. The encoded values are stored in the `Vector` `refs`. The `CategoricalPool` `pool` contains:

- `levels`: a mapping from the level-code to the category (`Vector{String}`, the "key" is the index)
- `invindex`: a mapping from the category to the level-code (`Dict{String, UInt32}`)

This structure can very efficiently be recoded. In many cases, we could create a categorical array with new categories without touching the refs at all by just swapping out the `pool` part that describes the code:

```
mapping = Dict("X"=>1, "Y"=>2, "Z"=>3)
b = CategoricalArray{Int64,1,UInt32}(undef, 0)
b.refs = a.refs
levels!(b.pool, [mapping[l] for l in levels(a.pool)])
```

In the actual `recode` function a new empty categorical array of the same length as `a` is created and more edge cases are considered (perhaps most importantly the case when multiple categories are collapsed into one in the new code).

The broadcasted `unwrap` then consists of simple lookups in the pool that Julia is able to optimize very well.

### Benchmarks

[Bogumił Kamiński's first solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67470218/15281224):

`@btime recode(unwrap.($a), "X"=>1, "Y"=>2, "Z"=>3)`

| length | btime result |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 1.268 μs (5 allocations: 1.84 KiB) |
| 1000 | 14.872 μs (5 allocations: 15.97 KiB) |
| 10000 | 151.881 μs (7 allocations: 156.50 KiB) |

[Bogumił Kamiński's second solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67470218/15281224):

`@btime [$mapping[v] for v in $a]`

| length | btime result |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 2.439 μs (101 allocations: 4.00 KiB) |
| 1000 | 23.715 μs (1001 allocations: 39.19 KiB) |
| 10000 | 240.292 μs (10002 allocations: 390.70 KiB) |

[Milan Bouchet-Valat's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67538359/15281224):

`@btime recode!(similar($a, Int), $a, "X"=>1, "Y"=>2, "Z"=>3)`

| length | btime result |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 2.158 μs (104 allocations: 4.09 KiB) |
| 1000 | 21.347 μs (1004 allocations: 39.28 KiB) |
| 10000 | 208.035 μs (10005 allocations: 390.80 KiB) |

This solution:

`@btime unwrap.(recode($a, "X"=>1, "Y"=>2, "Z"=>3))`

| length | btime result |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 2.360 μs (45 allocations: 4.56 KiB) |
| 1000 | 4.420 μs (45 allocations: 15.20 KiB) |
| 10000 | 20.212 μs (47 allocations: 120.55 KiB) |